# copy certain characters from one string to another in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to loop through a string1 and copy the alpha characters into a string3. The code I have so far is below, probably not the best but it works to a point and puts the letter into the first point of string3. However, the next time around it just overwrites that character until I am left with an empty string at the end. Does anyone know how to fix it so that it will save the element of string1 into the next free space in string3? Many thanks this is driving me crazy!!!

```
MOV DX,OFFSET STRING1+2 ; dx = address of string1
mov bx, dx       ; bx = dx = address of string1
mov ch, 0      ; set cx to string size for loop 
mov cl, [bx+1] 
; print prompt
call PTHIS       
db  13, 10, "removed non-alphanumeric characters1: ",0

remove_char:
; check if it's not a lower case letter:
cmp byte ptr [bx], 'a'
jg ok3          ; if char is 'a' or above, goto 'ok3'
cmp byte ptr [bx], 'z'
jl ok3                  ; if char is below 'z', goto 'ok3'
cmp [bx],'$'
je '$', next
; ... goto 'ok3' anyway... ("fall through")
inc bx ; next char.

ok3:
push [bx]
lea dx, string3+2 
pop [bx]
mov bh, [bx]
mov string3+2, bh
inc bx ; next char.
loop remove_char
```

Comment: I have never seen this syntax or instruction before. Can you help me understand it ?  `je '$', next`  I couldn't find it documented (but I only spent 5 minutes looking for it).

Comment: I am unable to understand why you push and pop in these three lines... 
`push [bx]  // why push ?  //// lea dx, string3+2 // Okay, point dx somewhere  //// pop [bx]   //  needless instruction, bx has not changed`  You `push` bx, then you don't do anything to bx, then you `pop bx`.  No clue why you are doing that (p.s., comment every line as well as you do the others and you'll see more bugs before they happen.)

Comment: Step through this with your debugger and let us know what happens after the `RET` statement in the `PTHIS` subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

After `mov cl, [bx+1]` check, whether `cx` is zero. If `cx` is zero, you have to break the loop at this point, because otherwise, the loop would be repeted 65536 times. Insert this code in the line after `mov cl, [bx+1]`:

```
cmp cx, 0
je exit
```

and insert a label `exit` (or whatever you want to insert) at the end. This makes sure, that the code is not executed if `cx` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you extract the length of the string from it's second byte? To me

```
MOV DX,OFFSET STRING1+2 ; dx = address of string1
```

suggests somewhat that the length would be stored in the prefixed word. If so use `mov cx,[bx-2]` and break out if CX turns out to be zero.

When you compare for a lowercase character you need to use `jge` and `jle`.

This instruction `mov bh,[bx]` destroys your pointer BX. Better use AL in stead of BH.

This instruction `mov string3+2, bh` makes no sense! Even if it does compile it will always store at the same location.